# Sum of fields and variable discounts

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to give a discount based on number of camp sessions signed up for: 2-3 sessions get a 5% discount; 3 or more sessions get a 10% discount. I tried the following formula:

```
=(if TotalNumberOfSessions > 3 then -0.1 else if TotalNumberOfSessions > 1 then -0.05 else 0) *TotalNumberofSessions
```

but I get this error message:

> Operator '>' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32' at character 26

and can't figure out what the message means.

Can you tell me the formula I need to use to calculate that?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. First, I would create a Price field (we'll call it Total Price) outside of your repeating sections. This field will sum the total price of all the camper sessions:

`=CamperInformation.Sum(Sessions_Amount)`

Next, create another Price field named Discount and use the .Count() function to retrieve the total number of sections and apply your discounts:

`=(if CamperInformation.Count() > 3 then -TotalPrice*0.10 else if CamperInformation.Count() > 1 then -TotalPrice*.05 else 0)`

As you can see, multiplying the Total Price by .10 or .05 will actually create a 10% or 5% discount off of the total. If you don't multiply them by the total, .10 and .05 are just static numbers.